Langchain DocArrayInMemorySearch not working
I'm trying to create a RAG program using Langchain and cannot get the DocArrayInMemorySearch function to work.
Image of error
I have correctly created the embeddings and keep on getting the same error. My Python drivers are up to date and I have the latest version of the Langchain libraries.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
